# How to enable query explanation for rails 3.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, explain

Is there any option to enable query explanation in Rails 3.1? I know there is such option for rails 3.2 and can be enabled with the following option in `config/<environment>.rb`

```
config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

So the question is if there are any similar workarounds for Rails 3.1?